# Eclipse Juno content assistent (CTRL-Space) not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having problems with eclipse Juno. Every time I do CTRL-Space a message error pops up saying “code assist took too long ...”. I’ve tried all the suggestions I found here on this site, but nothing seems to fix the problem.
Does anyone have any another suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try starting eclipse with the arguments...

```
-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ui.codeAssistTimeout=60000
```

Comment: I tried a gazillion different things, but nothing seemed to fix the problem. The only solution was to go back to eclipse indigo. Now everything is working fine.